# How to calculate the middlle coordinate/point on earth between two coordinates?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, spheres, geodesy

Good Afternoon.
I need help for a component of my math IA.
I need to calculate the middle point between two coordinates on earth to make calculations based on this. I (stupidly) attempted to use the midpoint formula (for a 2d plane) `(xM,Ym= (x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2)`. However, this ignores the fact that the earth is round (as I was told by my teacher) I used the `12.458467°, -71.664728°` format to use this formula.

How can I calculate the middle point in coordinates between two points on earth?
[e.g. Middle point/coordinate between 12.458467°, -71.664728° and -53.896306°, -71.294314°].

Comment: It's not always possible. What's the middle between North and South poles? The idea is that you need to draw the circle containing your two points, centered in the center of the Earth. Calculate the angle between the two points, as seen from the center of the Earth, then rotate on of the points by half the angle towards the other point, but around the axis perpendicular to this circle.

Comment: There are always at least two possible answers, depending on which way you go along the great circle containing the two points.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is this:

1. Calculate the 3D coordinates (x,y,z) of the two points. You can use 1 for the radius of the earth.
2. Take the midpoint between them. This is the midpoint of the straight line between them, so will be a point inside the earth, but it lies directly below the spot on the surface that you want.
3. Scale the coordinates to get that epicentre surface point. It is at distance 1 from the origin.
4. Calculate the longitute/latitude of the point.